# CSV manipulation problem. A little complex and would like the solution to not be using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

CSV file:

```
Acct,phn_1,phn_2,phn_3,Name,Consent,zipcode
1234,45678,78906,,abc,NCN,10010
3456,48678,,78976,def,NNC,10010
```

Problem:

Based on consent value which is for each of the phones (in 1st row: 1st N is phn_1, C for phn_2 and so on) I need to retain only that phn column and move the remaining columns to the end of the file.

The below is what I have. My approach isn't that great is what I feel. I'm trying to get the id of the individual Ns and Cs, get the id and map it with the phone (but I'm unable to iterate through the phn headers and compare the id's of the Ns and Cs)

```
with open('file.csv', 'rU') as infile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(infile) data = {} for row in reader:
       for header, value in row.items():
           data.setdefault(header, list()).append(value) # print(data)
           Consent = data['Consent']
       for i in range(len(Consent)):
           # print(list(Consent[i]))
       for idx, val in enumerate(list(Consent[i])):
           # print(idx, val)
       if val == 'C':
           #print("C")
           print(idx)
       else:
           print("N")
```

Could someone provide me with the solution for this?

Please Note: Do not want the solution to be by using pandas.

Comment: if 'C' then that phn value needs to be retained. 'N' and other columns to move to the end of file.

Comment: Dheeraj, stack overflow is not a forum which writes code for you. It is a forum that helps you troubleshoot your code and guide you to the answer. What code have you written so far that can motivate us to help you?

Comment: Hi Joe, i forgot abt my code. The below is what i have. My approach isnt that great is what i feel. Im trying to get the id of the individual Ns and Cs, get the id and map it with the phone (but im unable to iterate through the phn headers and compare the id's of the Ns and Cs):

Comment: with open('file.csv', 'rU') as infile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(infile)

  data = {}
  for row in reader:
    for header, value in row.items():
      data.setdefault(header, list()).append(value)
    # print(data)

Consent = data['Consent']
for i in range(len(Consent)):
    # print(list(Consent[i]))
    for idx, val in enumerate(list(Consent[i])):
        # print(idx, val)
        if val == 'C':
            #print("C")
            print(idx)
        else:
            print("N")

Comment: what does your output look like? I assume N means no consent and C means consent. For example, `3456,48678,,78976,def,NNC,10010` will result in `3456:[78976]` ?

Comment: outputs gotta be like say: 3456,48678,,78976,def,NNC,10010 looks like 3456,78976,def,NN,10010,48678,,

Comment: Post the desired output in the question section instead of the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll find my answer in the comments of the code below.

```py
import csv


def parse_csv(file_name):
    """ """

    # Prepare the output. Note that all rows of a CSV file must have the same structure.
    # So it is actually not possible to put the phone numbers with no consent at the end
    # of the file, but what you can do is to put them at the end of the row.
    # To ensure that the structure is the same on all rows, you need to put all phone numbers
    # at the end of the row. That means the phone number with consent is duplicated, and that
    # is not very efficient.
    # I chose to put the result in a string, but you can use other types.
    output = "Acct,phn,Name,Consent,zipcode,phn_1,phn_2,phn_3\n"

    with open(file_name, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:

            # Search the letter “C” in “Consent” and get the position of the first match.
            # Add one to the result because the “phn_×” keys are 1-based and not 0-based.
            first_c_pos = row["Consent"].find("C") + 1

            # If there is no “C”, then the “phn” key is empty.
            if first_c_pos == 0:
                row["phn"] = ""

            # If there is at least one “C”, create a key string that will take the values
            # phn_1, phn_2 or phn_3.
            else:
                key = f"phn_{first_c_pos}"
                row["phn"] = row[key]

            # Add the current row to the result string.
            output += ",".join([
                row["Acct"], row["phn"], row["Name"], row["Consent"],
                row["zipcode"], row["phn_1"], row["phn_2"], row["phn_3"]
            ])
            output += "\n"

    # Return the string.
    return(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = parse_csv("file.csv")
    print(output)
```